# PrestaShop email localization

Tags: prestashop

I am developing a module for PrestaShop 1.5.

I am sending email like this(the documentation is really missing, i studied other default components and this is what i got so far)

```
Mail::Send(
                            $this->context->language->id, //int $id_lang
                            'template_name',//string $template
                            //Mail::l('Hello', $this->context->language->id),//string $subject
                            $this->l('Email subject'),//string $subject
                            array('{discount}' => $code,
                                  '{firstname}' => $customer['firstname'],
                                  '{lastname}' => $customer['lastname'],
                                  '{img_url}' => $img_url,
                                  '{valid_days}' => $form['days_valid']  
                            ),//string $template_vars
                            $customer['email'],//string $to
                            implode(' ', array_filter( array( $customer['firstname'], $customer['lastname']) )),
                            strval( Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL') ),//string $from
                            strval( Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME') ),//string $from_name
                            /* null,//string $from
                            null//string $from_name */
                            null,//array $file_attachment
                            null,//$mode_smtp
                            $template_path//string $template_path /*__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->name.'/mails/' */

                    );
```

Note i tried using

```
Mail::l('Hello', $this->context->language->id),//string $subject
```

and

```
$this->l('Email subject'),//string $subject
```

as the email's subject.

And i keep getting "No Subject was found for ...". What the customer receive is the hardcoded string i put in the source code.

So how to get rid of this error:
[image]
Plus the emails are sent in apparently random language(sometimes english, sometimes italian).

Answer (score 3):

In your module, you must use Mail::l() in the subject parameter.
Here's an example of Mail::Send() for a module :

```
Mail::Send($this->context->language->id,
    'test',
    Mail::l('test subject', $this->context->language->id),
    array(),
    $to_email);
```

---

Here how email translations is working :

AdminTranslationsController will check in "/modules/[module folder]/mails/" for the templates and in "/mails/[lang]/lang.php" for subjects. Subjects will be created when submitting translations.

---

If that doesn'work, maybe it's a problem with folder's rights.
Open this file :

> /prestashop/mails/it/lang.php

And check if there's a line like this one :

```
$_LANGMAIL['Email subject'] = 'translation in italian';
```

If not, check web server rights on this file and parent folders.

Comment: but i need this done automatically upon component install and in a way that it doesn't get deleted should the user modify some label

Comment: it's automatically done if you use `Mail::l('Email subject', $this->context->language->id)` in the subject parameter of Mail::Send.

Comment: i'm extending Module and you are talking about Controllers, something is not right

Comment: I'm just talking about AdminTranslationsController that manage translations to explain how its work is done.
For your module, just read the 1st paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I've now came over same issue working with Prestashop version 1.5.5.0.

In some circumstances, getSubjectMail() method won't recognize email template, so it cannot be matched with subject. The whole point is that while this method looks for subjects to be translated, it parses php files as plain text. Therefore all variables are parsed unresolved.

In my case, I'm calling Mail:Send from the module's controller and it looks like:

```
Mail::Send(
    $id_lang,
    $template, // <- don't use variable here, rather type email template there directly.
    Mail::l('Message from footer contact form'),
    $template_vars,
    $contact->email,
    $contact->name,
    ($is_email ? $from : Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL')),
    '',
    null, // file attachment
    null, // mode smtp
    $this->module->_mailpath
);
```

Parsing this file would result into matching subject **Message from footer contact form** to the mail template "**$template**". Which doesn't exist obviously.

To make sure that your subject will be recognized correctly, don't use variable to pass template name.

Comment: The key is to not use a variable!! Amazingly bad design from PrestaShop, and obscure limitation.

Answer (score 1):

The email templates (and not only them) are totally messy in Presta. Since I installed a custom theme I have them now in 6(!!) different locations.

Would not be such a trouble, but it seems that gets the same confused as I did. It takes the templates from one location for editing them, saves them in turn into another location, and takes them from a third location (for a module) when actually creating the mail.

As a result I was able to edit a template once, but after saving it, it appeared to be reverted, because it was actually saved to another location.

So what I did is: I removed the templates for the module ("mailalerts") from the default theme folder (both folder 'mails' and 'modules/mailalerts/mails') and from my custom theme.

If you do so - just keep a copy before you delete them, because you will probably loose some of the translations you already made there.

Decide for one and only one location where you want to keep them (for me it were the original 'mails' resp 'modules' folders) and edit them then later only from this one location. For the locations mentioned here you choose the option "Core" from the dropdown on the "Translations" admin page.